# Error: Form elements must not be named "submit"

Tags: jquery

When submitting an upload form, an alert shows up: `Error: Form elements must not be named "submit".` And no, I don't have any form elements with the name `submit`.  I'm using jQuery version 1.3.2.

What's the fix for this?

Comment: A little code/html would be useful

Comment: Try validating your markup at w3c http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just saw the problem.  It's in line 54 of the jquery.form.js file which says

```
$(':input[@name=submit]', form).length
```

From [API/1.3/Selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors), it says that

> Note: In jQuery 1.3 [@attr] style selectors were removed (they were previously deprecated in jQuery 1.2). Simply remove the '@' symbol from your selectors in order to make them work again.

I probably got the problem when I replaced my jQuery version from 1.2 to 1.3.  Now, I either have to modify that line or replace my version of jquery.form.js.

Answer (score 0):

In Form.js Check the Code Below You can see this Error Why can you get the Pop up For the Error,Error Code is Below...

```
 if ($(':input[name=submit],:input[id=submit]', form).length) {

    // if there is an input with a name or id of 'submit' then we won't be
    // able to invoke the submit fn on the form (at least not x-browser)

    alert('Error: Form elements must not have name or id of "submit".');
    return;
    }
```

So Now you understand Why u can get this Error,Now Solution is very Easy..

```
Step 1--> Check Your  input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"
```

Above Code is Not Working in the Form So Change Something Below That I have Changed Below As So Far..

```
    enter code here

input type="submit" name="save" id="save"
```

thats It.